# Multiple targets with different configurations build by each target in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, target

I want to ask something important for my project.

I need to create multiple projects using a single Xcode project. Each subproject will be later a different iOS app in the App Store. To do this I know that exists the concept of target but I want to configure differents enviorments for each targets, for example:

TargetOne: Dev configuration | AdHoc configuration | Prod configuration

TargetTwo: Dev configuration  | AdHoc configuration | Prod configuration

TargetThree: Dev configuration  | AdHoc configuration | Prod configuration

¿How can achieve this?

Comment: Why cannot u simply drag and drop the .xcodeporj file to a one single project in xcode u can always select that .xcodeproj in xocde and do the whatever settings.Everyone do like that na

Comment: Each target has it's own build settings and configurations, so.... not sure what the question here is.